# Consensus Algorithm converges then diverges again

Tags: multi-agent, swarm

I am trying to implement a consensus algorithm to command a swarm of 50 robots.
The robots 'communication is modeled by a complete undirected graph. when simulating the process I noticed that the robots converge to the average of the initial states, which is expected. However, After converging to the same point, they diverge again from that same point and each robot goes on a different direction. It is like they implode and then they explode.
I am new to this so I don't know what to expect, but I assumed that the simulation would stop when the robots converge.
Is what's happening norman? (I am using matlab , and I am pretty sure that my consensus equation is correct $\dot{x}(t)=-L.x(t)$  where $L=$degree matrix - adjacency matrix is the Laplacian matrix)

Comment: I'm working on the same problem, I have just finished my bibliographic research. we can collaborate to tackle this problem. You can contact me in this mail: charaf_abdelkarim.mosbah@g.enp.edu.dz

Comment: Please edit your final (parenthesized sentence) for clarity.